# Join two MySQL results by a common column

Tags: mysql, join

I have one table for the data, in such a format:

```
| Country1 | Name1 | 9.98 |  
| Country2 | Name2 | 8.98 |  
| Country1 | Name3 | 8.97 |
```

What I want to show up is this:

```
| Country  | x<10 | x<9 | etc  
| Country1 |  2   |  1  |   
| Country2 |  1   |  1  |
```

I have this query, but it is putting the two results together (it shows Australia twice, for example).

```
SELECT Country,COUNT(*) AS `sub10` FROM `allsub10` WHERE `Time`<10 GROUP BY `Country`

UNION ALL

SELECT Country,COUNT(*) AS `sub9` FROM `allsub10` WHERE `Time`<9 GROUP BY `Country`

ORDER BY `sub10` DESC
```

How could I select the count of all times less than 10, then 9, etc. while keeping the 'Country' column joined?

Comment: count for country 2 when x<9 should be i guess 1  because 8.98 is less than 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Country
, sum(if(`Time`<10,1,0)) as `x<10`
, sum(if(`Time`<9,1,0)) as `x<9`
, sum(if(`Time`<8,1,0)) as `x<8`
 FROM `allsub10`
 GROUP BY `Country`
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` put the column in the same position together, so the result of the given query will be

```
| Country  | x < 10  
--row where x < 10
| Country1 |  2   
| Country2 |  1   
--row where x < 9
| Country1 |  1
```

to get the different values in different columns you need to have them in the queries

```
SELECT Country, SUM(`sub10`) `sub10`, SUM(`sub9`) `sub9`, ...
FROM   (SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS `sub10`, 0 AS `sub9`, ... 
        FROM   `allsub10` 
        WHERE  `Time`<10 
        GROUP BY `Country`

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Country, 0 AS `sub10`,COUNT(*) AS `sub9`, ...  
        FROM   `allsub10` 
        WHERE  `Time`<9 
        GROUP BY `Country`) a
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY `sub10` DESC
```

or, without the `UNION`, it's possible to use a `CASE` to give a condition to the subject of the `COUNT`

```
SELECT Country
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `Time` < 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `sub10`
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `Time` < 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `sub9`
     , ...  
FROM `allsub10` 
GROUP BY `Country`
```

Answer (score -1):

Use distinct? SELECT distinct Country,... or even on the count so count(distinct...